# Updating two different plots based on two separate dropdown selections

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I am working on a project where we have two separate dropdowns with UFC fighter names. When a name is selected on both dropdowns a plot is supposed to come up showing data we have available for the fighters KD over time. I am working on making the two separate plots for the selections from the dropdown. I worked on something similar to this before (only difference was that we had only one dropdown instead of two) and to make the plot change based on the dropdown selection we used an "optionsChanged" function which was linked to our html.
My issue now is that I can make the plot work and change with dropdown selection for only one dropdown but I'm not sure how to do the same thing for the second dropdown.

This is the JavaScript code which makes the dropdowns with the "optionsChange" function that calls the second function that makes the plots. The first name displayed is first fighter in the data.

```
function init() {
  d3.json("http://127.0.0.1:5000/fighters").then(data => {

  // Drop down menu creation
  let dropdownMenu = d3.select("#selDataset");
  data.forEach((uniqueVarietyList) => {
  dropdownMenu.append('option').text(uniqueVarietyList)
 })

  let dropdownMenu2 = d3.select("#selDataset1");
  data.forEach((uniqueVarietyList) => {
  dropdownMenu2.append('option').text(uniqueVarietyList)
 })

 // Start at fighter option 0
 var result = data[0];

});

}


function optionChanged(fighter) {
 init(fighter);
 visuals(fighter);

}
```

This is the JavaScript code to make the plot for the selected option for one dropdown

```
function visuals(fighter){
 console.log('fighter' , fighter)
 d3.json(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/combined/${fighter}`).then( data => { 
 let combined_data=data;
 console.log(data);
 console.log()

    
    let dte= [];
    let KD= [];

    for(var i = 0; i<combined_data.length; i++) {
      combined_data[i].avg_KD
      KD.push(combined_data[i].avg_KD);
    }
    console.log(KD);

    
    for(var i = 0; i<combined_data.length; i++) {
      combined_data[i].date
      dte.push(combined_data[i].date);
    }
    
    

    var data = [
      {
        x: dte,
        y: KD,
        type: 'histogram',
      marker: {
        color: '#C70039',
        line: {
          color:  "rgba(255, 100, 102, 1)",
          width: 1
        }
      },
      }
    ];
    let barLayout= {
      title: 'KD History',
      margin: {t:0},
      hovermode: "closest",
      xaxis: {title: 'Date'},
      yaxis: {title:'KD'},
      margin: {t:30}
    };
    Plotly.newPlot('bar', data,barLayout);


});
}
```

This is the section in the html code where the plots and the dropdown are. The main areas of interest are in the two card-body classes.

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="bg-image hover-overlay ripple" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
                      <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/kickboxer-with-overlays-his-hands-prays-before-fight_392761-4654.jpg?w=2000" class="img-fluid" />
                      <a href="#!">
                        <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.15);"></div>
                      </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                      <select id="selDataset" onchange="optionChanged(this.value)"></select>    
                      <h5 class="card-title">Athlete Name</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
                      <div id="sample-metadata" class="panel-body"></div>
                      </p>
                      <div id="bar"></div>
                      <!-- need an actaul button -->
                      <button onclick="fighter1()" class="btn btn-primary"> Athlete UFC Page Stats</button>
                      <!-- <a href="https://www.ufc.com/rankings" class="btn btn-primary">Athlete UFC Page Stats</a> -->
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="bg-image hover-overlay ripple" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
                      <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/mixed-martial-artist-wraps-bandages-around-his-fist-concept-mma-ufc-thai-boxing-classic-boxing-mixed-media_392761-2633.jpg?w=2000" class="img-fluid" />
                      <a href="#!">
                        <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.15);"></div>
                      </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                      <select id="selDataset1" onchange="optionsChanged(this.value)"></select>
                      <h5 class="card-title">Athlete Name</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
                      <div id="sample-metadata3" class="panel-body"></div>
                      </p>
                      <div id="bar2"></div>
                      <button onclick="fighter2()" class="btn btn-primary"> Athlete UFC Page Stats</button>
                      <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Athlete UFC Page Stats</a> -->
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

P.s: The plot function is in a different Js file from the dropdown and options changed function
This is what our page looks like with the options change working for only one dropdown selection
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

I added a second function, "optionsChanged" to the first js script

```
function init() {
 d3.json("http://127.0.0.1:5000/fighters").then(data => {
 // Drop down menu creation
 let dropdownMenu = d3.select("#selDataset");
 data.forEach((uniqueVarietyList) => {
   dropdownMenu.append('option').text(uniqueVarietyList)
 })
 let dropdownMenu2 = d3.select("#selDataset1");
 data.forEach((uniqueVarietyList) => {
   dropdownMenu2.append('option').text(uniqueVarietyList)
 })

 // Start at fighter option 0
 var result = data[0];

});

}

function optionChanged(fighter) {
 init(fighter);
 visuals(fighter);

}
function optionsChanged(fighterr) {
 init(fighterr);
 visuals2(fighterr);

}
```

In the  second js script with the plot I made a second function just like the first function and only changed the variable from "fighter" to "fighterr".

```
function visuals(fighter){
 console.log('fighter' , fighter)
 d3.json(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/combined/${fighter}`).then( data => { 
 let combined_data=data;
 console.log(data);
 console.log()


let dte= [];
let KD= [];

for(var i = 0; i<combined_data.length; i++) {
  combined_data[i].avg_KD
  KD.push(combined_data[i].avg_KD);
}
console.log(KD);


for(var i = 0; i<combined_data.length; i++) {
  combined_data[i].date
  dte.push(combined_data[i].date);
}



var data = [
  {
    x: dte,
    y: KD,
    type: 'histogram',
  marker: {
    color: '#C70039',
    line: {
      color:  "rgba(255, 100, 102, 1)",
      width: 1
    }
  },
  }
];
let barLayout= {
  title: 'KD History',
  margin: {t:0},
  hovermode: "closest",
  xaxis: {title: 'Date'},
  yaxis: {title:'KD'},
  margin: {t:30}
};
Plotly.newPlot('bar', data,barLayout);


});
}

function visuals2(fighterr){
 console.log('fighter' , fighterr)
 d3.json(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/combined/${fighterr}`).then( data => { 
 let combined_data=data;
 console.log(data);
 console.log()


let dte= [];
let KD= [];

for(var i = 0; i<combined_data.length; i++) {
  combined_data[i].avg_KD
  KD.push(combined_data[i].avg_KD);
}
console.log(KD);


for(var i = 0; i<combined_data.length; i++) {
  combined_data[i].date
  dte.push(combined_data[i].date);
}



var data = [
  {
    x: dte,
    y: KD,
    type: 'histogram',
  marker: {
    color: '#C70039',
    line: {
      color:  "rgba(255, 100, 102, 1)",
      width: 1
    }
  },
  }
];
let barLayout= {
  title: 'KD History',
  margin: {t:0},
  hovermode: "closest",
  xaxis: {title: 'Date'},
  yaxis: {title:'KD'},
  margin: {t:30}
};
Plotly.newPlot('bar2', data,barLayout);


});
}
```

The html script was left unchanged.

This is what the new solution looks like and each dropdown updates the separate plots independently of each other exactly how I expected it to.
[image]